# In storm 1.0.2, kafka-spout consume same data repeatdely every restarting topology

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm currently developing storm version up project 0.9.6->1.0.2
My spout did not start reading from the latest offset even though use same spout id in SpoutConfig constructor. 
Oh, I did not delete zookeeper data, just delete storm-data.

I changed my project configuration and source like below
1. storm-core and storm-kafka version change 0.9.6 to 1.0.2 and kafka_2.10 0.8.2.2 in pom.xml.
2. change package path 
- backtype -> org.apache
- storm.kafka -> org.apache.storm.kafka
3. Change serializing code byte[] to ByteBuffer in Custom Scheme(I used AVRO class)

I started topology and my spout consumer start to read specific offset value.
My topology read data like this, even though restart the topology, consume same data every restart.

data 1 -> data 2 -> data 3
(restart topology)
data 1 -> data 2 -> data 3

Before change version, consume next data correctly like this, even though restart the topology. 
data 1 -> data 2 -> data 3
(restart topology)
data 4 -> data 5 -> data 6
(restart topology)
data 7 -> data 8 -> data 9

I didn't change zkRoot value in SpoutConfig.(I think it means kafka group id)
How can i fix this problem?

Thanks and regards

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I am having similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check spoutConfig.startOffsetTime
it can be kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime() or kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime()